# Unity videoplayer cannot play clip

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do the platformer game tutorial from the unity hub but I can't progress through the tutorial or do anything because I get the error `VideoPlayer cannot play clip : Assets/Tutorials/Playtest/WT-Select-Gameobject.mov`. I checked myself to see if the file was there and it is.

This is what my screen looks like.

[image: my screen]

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? Show the Inspector of the video player, your code or whatever you are using that allows everyone to reproduce the same issue in a new project ... Or at least the link to whatever tutorial you are following

Comment: I haven't written any code so far and the tutorial is one of the Unity ones in the Unity hub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Unity on Linux.
The Unity video player does not support .mov files on Linux.

Refer to this page for more information:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html